# How to crawl a site with server-generated content?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am writing a simple php crawler that gets data from a website and inserts it into my database.  I start with a predefined url.  Then I go through the the contents of the page (from php's file_get_contents) and eventually use `file_get_contents` on links of that page.  The url's I am getting from the links are fine when I echo them and then open them from my browser on their own.  However, when I use `file_get_contents` and then echo the result, the page does not appear correctly because of errors related to dynamically created server-side data from the site.  The echo'd page contents do not include the listed data from the server that I need, because it cannot find necessary resources for the site.

It appears relative paths in the echo'd webpage are not allowing the desired content to be generated.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Any help is appreciated!

Here is some of my code so far:

```
function crawl_all($url)
{
    $main_page = file_get_contents($url);

    while(strpos($main_page, '"fl"') > 0)
    {   
        $subj_start  = strpos($main_page, '"fl"');      // get start of subject row
        $main_page   = substr($main_page, $subj_start); // cut off everything before subject row
        $link_start  = strpos($main_page, 'href') + 6;  // get the start of the subject link
        $main_page   = substr($main_page, $link_start); // cut off everything before subject link
        $link_end    = strpos($main_page, '">') - 1;    // get the end of the subject link
        $link_length = $link_end + 1;             
        $link = substr($main_page, 0, $link_length);    // get the subject link

        crawl_courses('https://whatever.com' . $link);      
    }
}

/* Crawls all the courses for a subject. */
function crawl_courses($url)
{
    $subj_page = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $url;           // website looks fine when in opened in browser
    echo $subj_page;     // when echo'd, the page does not contain most of the server-side generated data i need

    while(strpos($subj_page, '<td><a href') > 0)
    {
        $course_start = strpos($subj_page, '<td><a href');
        $subj_page    = substr($subj_page, $course_start);
        $link_start   = strpos($subj_page, 'href') + 6;
        $subj_page    = substr($subj_page, $link_start);
        $link_end     = strpos($subj_page, '">') - 1;
        $link_length  = $link_end + 1;
        $link = substr($subj_page, 0, $link_length);

        //crawl_professors('https://whatever.com' . $link);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't content grabbed from an ajax call?

Comment: here is one of my errors: GET http://web.engr.illinois.edu/ResourceServingWebapp/rs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery-1.3.2.min.js (404 not found) ... it tries to look for the resource with my website path prepended

Comment: Another error is 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'.

Comment: Try use a DOM parser for a start.  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What is the url u are getting that error from?

Comment: Also CURL is a better option for getting the website contents.

Comment: Essentially, all the errors outputted to the console are because the resources the echo'd page tries to get are looked for under my website's path.  Will CURL prevent that from happening, and allow the page to be loaded in its original context?

Comment: can you give an example of the url you are calling and the output fro m file_get_contents where its being rewritten?

Answer (score 0):

Try advance html dom parser. It is here....
http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/